# Display all possible results from 3 mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have three tables in one mysql table.

```
Table1 = number1
Table2 = number2
Table3 = number3
```

Now I would like to get all possible combinations of these and want to save it in a new table allnumbers. How to do something like these?

Comment: Try using cross join `SELECT t1.number1, t2.number2, t3.number3 from table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3`

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT number1 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT number2 FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT number3 FROM table3
```

If you want to create a new table from this result set:

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable
AS
SELECT ...
...
```

Comment: I don't need a for or while function?

Comment: @TrivoXx - What do you mean? Where is the for or the while function? This is just a single query.

Comment: I also want to see it on my php.

Comment: @TrivoXx - OK, then put this query and run it in PHP.